# Can all html forms be submitted programmatically?

Tags: java, selenium, http-post

Currently, I am using `Selenium API` to populate and submit fields on a form. There is a servlet in the back end of the form.

This form works as follows:

1. When I click the submit button, the form sends a `POST` request to the server, but the data gets saved only for the current session.
2. Then I need to click the `Save` button, and then the browser send a second `POST` request to the server, and the data gets finally saved.

When I tried to replicate the exact same `POST` requests without Selenium, simply using `Java`, I got `200 OK` responses for both `POST` requests, but the data did not get saved. Does the `200 OK` mean my data got submitted correctly ? I have experience sending data to forms, and everything always worked fine for me.

This form is weird in a way that one has to click `Submit`, and then the browser redirects you, and then you click `Save`. I used `Live Headers`, and replicated ALL POST and GET requests word-to-word, and got `200 OK` for all requests. But no data was saved on the server's side. Why ?  Is there any protection I don't know about. Please give me any hint

Comment: Are the request headers/cookies the same in both cases?

Comment: I used Live Headers plug in: YES the cookies are the same, the same session. It's just that when you click Submit, the data saves only temporarily. You also have to click 'Save' to make sure it's saved

Comment: The only way to find out what really happens is to debug the servlet code. If you don't own the code you can try to put a proxy between and log the whole traffic to see the difference between the selenium call and the Java request.

Comment: Is there any way Selenium can spool all the traffic ? How do I put a proxy ?

Comment: There are several such proxies, e.g. [Peter Bennett's General Purpose Proxy and debug tool](http://proxpy.sourceforge.net/usage.html). You configure the proxy to connect to the servlet. And selenium and your Java client connect to the proxy. The proxy forwards the request as is but is able to log the whole traffic.